# RabbitMQ ack on pub/sub

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ 3.6.x

I have a fanout exchange with 2 queues registered. All works fine.

But silly question in pub/sub fanout model, can/should the consumer do acknowledgements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consumers always have to acknowledgement messages!

Maybe the question is `auto_ack` yes or not.

> But silly question in pub/sub fanout model, can/should the consumer do
>   acknowledgements?

Even if pub/sub usually implements auto-delete, exclusive queues with `auto_ack = true`, there is not a specific rule !

it depends from your application! :)

Comment: sillier question, when we have multiple cosumers, when exactly is it acknowledged, when one consumer acks it or all consumers? How does it even know how many sacks to wait for :O or before considering it acked it might hv failed to reach 90% cosnumers